# R equivalent to MATLAB's 'tokens' option in regexp

Tags: regex, r, matlab

I am learning about regexp and have not been able to find an R's equivalent to MATLAB's `tokens` [option](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/tokens-in-regular-expressions.html):

```
hstr = '<!comment><a name="752507"></a><b>Default</b><br>';
expr = '<(\w+).*?>.*?</\1>';

[mat,tok] = regexp(hstr, expr, 'match', 'tokens');

mat{:}
ans =
<a name="752507"></a>
ans =
<b>Default</b>

tok{:}
ans = 
    'a'
ans = 
    'b'
```

What would be the best way to achieve this in R?

Comment: What's the dedired output? (Some folks don't have MATLAB.)

Comment: @lukeA I ran this code in MATLAB R2015a and added the exact output.

Comment: Hmm you got `regmatches(hstr, gregexpr('<(\\w+).*?>.*?</\\1>', hstr))[[1]]` and `regmatches(hstr, regexec('<(\\w+).*?>.*?</\\1>', hstr))[[1]]`. I'm not aware of a function that combines both. (However, that doesn't mean there is none - let's see.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`str_match_all`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_match_all) function from the `stringr` library to return all matches and submatches (=captured texts).

```
> library(stringr)
> hstr = '<!comment><a name="752507"></a><b>Default</b><br>'
> expr = '<(\\w+).*?>.*?</\\1>'
> results = str_match_all(hstr, expr)
> unlist(results[[1]][,2])
[1] "a" "b"
> results
[[1]]
     [,1]                      [,2]
[1,] "<a name=\"752507\"></a>" "a" 
[2,] "<b>Default</b>"          "b"
```

As you see, Column 1 in `results` contains matches, and Column 2 contains captured substrings.

There is also an option to grab them all with base R:

```
> sapply(regmatches(hstr,gregexpr(expr,hstr))[[1]], function(m) unlist(regmatches(m,regexec(expr,m))))
     <a name="752507"></a>     <b>Default</b>  
[1,] "<a name=\"752507\"></a>" "<b>Default</b>"
[2,] "a"                       "b"
```

But note that [`regexec`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) does not support PCRE regex flavor. It might be a problem in specific situations when you need lookarounds or skip-fail verbs.